# Checkboxpreference listener

Tags: android

I have to have many checkboxpreference in preferncescreen and have to register each checkbox value changed and do some task based on if its on or off.How do I do this in checkboxpreference?
I know to do this in checkbox with the below code:

```
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
            // Is the view now checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.Activate:
            if (checked){
                // Put some meat on the sandwich
                Toast.makeText(Daydream.this, "checked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else
                // Remove the meat
                Toast.makeText(Daydream.this, "UNchecked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.sencond_id:
            if (checked){
                // Cheese me
            }else
                // I'm lactose intolerant
            break;
        // TODO: Veggie sandwich
    }
}
```

But I dont know to do this with checkboxpreference.Is there any way to do like above?I know that the preferencescreen is deprecated but I have to use it because of simplicity to make two lines of listview.I hope I get a reply soon.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use it something like this

```
final Preference otherpref = (Preference) findPreference("otherpref"); 
final Preference pref = (Preference) findPreference("checkbox");        

pPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true; 
}
});

otherpref .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Other text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true; 
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks...Although this not what I was looking for,it worked for me.