# if() in a Settings Activity

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm a Android-Beginner and want to make a if-question in my settings/preferences-Activity.

Here is my Preferences.java:

```
package net.dominik.genpush;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

...and my Prefs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pushCheckBox"
        android:title="@string/pushnachr_headline"
        android:summary="@string/pushnachr_explain"
        android:defaultValue="true">

    </CheckBoxPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now I wanted to make something like

```
public void onCheckboxPush(View b)
    {
        if (pushCheckBox.isChecked())
        {
           //CODE
        }
        else...
```

but don't know how I can start the methode when the checkbox changes.
In a other way I could use

android:onClick="MethodeNameHere" in my activity.xml-File. This don't work in my PreferenceActivity class so no message.

Is there a (easy) way to do something like the "onClick" in a similar manner?

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271717/checkboxpreference-listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set listener for checkbox.

```
CheckBoxPreference checkBox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pushCheckBox");
checkBox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
                //your code here
                return true;
            }
});
```

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html#onPreferenceChange(android.preference.Preference,%20java.lang.Object)) return true will update the state of the Preference with the new value.

And simply check inside of listener if checkBox is checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answere. 
What should I do in the onPreferenceChange methode? Because android studio want to have a return argument

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to make one attribute depend on another, you can use the `android:dependency` attribute. Will that do what you want? E.g.,

```
    <CheckBoxPreference
         android:key="pushCheckBox"
         android:title="@string/pushnachr_headline"
         android:summary="@string/pushnachr_explain"
         android:defaultValue="true">

    <!-- This setting will be disabled if pref_one is not checked -->
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="preference_two"
        android:dependency="pushCheckBox"
        android:title="Pref Two" />
```

But, if you really just want to get the click event to do something else, put something like this in the `onResume` method.

```
Preference pushCheckBox = findPreference("pushCheckBox");
pushCheckBox.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

        // do something here

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answere, but Its not that what I wanted.
I think @bgplaya is going the right way :)